# drbd can't start resync

Tags: drbd

This is my situation

On both nodes

```
    cat /etc/drbd.d/*
resource clustervol {
device /dev/drbd1;
disk /dev/sdb1;
meta-disk internal;

on iscsi1 {
address 192.168.0.30:7790;
}
on iscsi2 {
address 192.168.0.41:7790;
}
}

global {
    usage-count yes;
    # minor-count dialog-refresh disable-ip-verification
}

common {
    protocol C;

    handlers {
    # The following 3 handlers were disabled due to #576511.
    # Please check the DRBD manual and enable them, if they make sense in your setup.
    # pri-on-incon-degr "/usr/lib/drbd/notify-pri-on-incon-degr.sh; /usr/lib/drbd/notify-emergency-reboot.sh; echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger ; reboot -f";
    # pri-lost-after-sb "/usr/lib/drbd/notify-pri-lost-after-sb.sh; /usr/lib/drbd/notify-emergency-reboot.sh; echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger ; reboot -f";
    # local-io-error "/usr/lib/drbd/notify-io-error.sh; /usr/lib/drbd/notify-emergency-shutdown.sh; echo o > /proc/sysrq-trigger ; halt -f";

    # fence-peer "/usr/lib/drbd/crm-fence-peer.sh";
    # split-brain "/usr/lib/drbd/notify-split-brain.sh root";
    # out-of-sync "/usr/lib/drbd/notify-out-of-sync.sh root";
    # before-resync-target "/usr/lib/drbd/snapshot-resync-target-lvm.sh -p 15 -- -c 16k";
    # after-resync-target /usr/lib/drbd/unsnapshot-resync-target-lvm.sh;
}

startup {
    # wfc-timeout degr-wfc-timeout outdated-wfc-timeout wait-after-sb
}

disk {
    # on-io-error fencing use-bmbv no-disk-barrier no-disk-flushes
    # no-disk-drain no-md-flushes max-bio-bvecs
}

net {
    # sndbuf-size rcvbuf-size timeout connect-int ping-int ping-timeout max-buffers
    # max-epoch-size ko-count allow-two-primaries cram-hmac-alg shared-secret
    # after-sb-0pri after-sb-1pri after-sb-2pri data-integrity-alg no-tcp-cork
}

syncer {
    # rate after al-extents use-rle cpu-mask verify-alg csums-alg
}
```

}

On node1 works all

```
    version: 8.3.11 (api:88/proto:86-96)
srcversion: F937DCB2E5D83C6CCE4A6C9 
 1: cs:StandAlone ro:Primary/Unknown ds:UpToDate/DUnknown   r----s
    ns:0 nr:0 dw:0 dr:996 al:0 bm:0 lo:0 pe:0 ua:0 ap:0 ep:1 wo:f oos:29359164
```

On node2 no

```
cat /proc/drbd 
version: 8.3.11 (api:88/proto:86-96)
srcversion: F937DCB2E5D83C6CCE4A6C9 

 1: cs:WFConnection ro:Secondary/Unknown ds:Diskless/DUnknown C r-----
    ns:0 nr:0 dw:0 dr:0 al:0 bm:0 lo:0 pe:0 ua:0 ap:0 ep:1 wo:f oos:0
```

I have tried a lot of command: disconnect,invalidate,discard my data
on node2,but the situation doesn't change
Is a "virgin" dbrd configuration,i have no data on disk
how to force a resync?
Thanks

Comment: Of course network is ok,and nodes can ping each all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dirty and quick solution removed and recreate virtual disk(i'm on vm for testing)
then
on primary

```
drbdadm create-md clustervol
drbdadm primary --force clustervol
drbdadm -- --overwrite-data-of-peer primary clustervol
service drbd restart
```

on secondary

```
drbdadm secondary all
service drbd restart
```